# adding images to cursor on JS event

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I attach an image to the cursor on this event below. Here is the path to the icon I want to attach to the cursor - https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-128.png
I want this cursor-icon to display only when the mouse is being moved to the right.
Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide your html, css and js files. And create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use javascript, to connect on mouseover event for each pannel with scroll page postition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to each of your panels, for example:

```
li.flower {
    cursor: cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I am looking for. Every time you start moving your mouse to the right (no matter what panel you are on) - it should show this arrow https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/next-128.png        OR   when moving our mouse to the left, it should change the png/ico to this https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/previous-128.png

Comment: It looks like you are firing an event when you go to the right....  all you need to do is attach a cursor image to that event.  For example:

$('body').css('cursor', 'url("right-arrow.img")');

This is not a working example, but more of a general example.